# Gives Seg fault when I try to change the values of the array and If I declare the array without malloc

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I am trying to implement Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm. For that I have created an adjacency list to represent the graph and it is giving correct output but the problem is whenever I try to declare the array using `distance_array_new[(graph -> no_vertices)]` it gives a segfault, also when I try to change the values of the array. I cannot even check the pointer for `NULL`, it gives a segfault.

I tried to check the pointer for `NULL`.
I tried to check using numbers. eg- 5, 6.
Nothing Worked.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* The graph vertices are labeled as 1,2,3,4,5 but represented as 0,1,2,3,4 */
typedef struct ListNode{
    int vertex_number;
    int weight;
    struct ListNode* next;
}Node;

typedef struct Graph {
    int no_vertices;
    int source;
    int total_weight;
    Node* list;

}Graph;

Graph* initialize_graph(FILE *fnodes, Graph *graph) {
    int total_vertex, source;
    fscanf(fnodes, "%d,%d", &total_vertex, &source);
    graph -> no_vertices = total_vertex;
    graph -> source = source;
    graph -> list = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node) * (graph->no_vertices));

    return graph;
}

Node* adjacency_list(FILE *fnodes, Graph * graph) {
    int total_weight=0, start, end, weight;
    Node *temp;
    Node *trav = graph -> list;
    // Preprocessing of the adjacency list
    for (int i = 0; i < graph->no_vertices; ++i)
    {
        graph -> list[i].vertex_number = i; // to represent each vertex
        graph -> list[i].next = NULL;
    }


    while(fscanf(fnodes, "%d,%d,%d", &start, &end, &weight) == 3) {
        temp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        temp -> vertex_number = end;
        temp -> next = NULL;
        temp -> weight = weight;
        trav  = &(graph -> list[start - 1]);
        while(trav -> next != NULL) {
            trav = trav -> next;
        }
        trav -> next = temp;
        total_weight += weight;
    }
    graph -> total_weight = total_weight;
    return graph -> list;
}

void print(Graph *graph) {
    Node* trav = graph -> list;
    for (int i = 0; i < graph -> no_vertices; ++i)
    {
        trav = &(graph -> list[i]);
        printf("Vertex no. : %d ", graph -> list[i].vertex_number);
        while (trav -> next != NULL) {
            printf("DEST : %d \n", trav -> next -> vertex_number);
            trav = trav -> next;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main() {
    FILE *fnodes = fopen("nodes.txt", "r");
    Graph *graph;
    graph = initialize_graph(fnodes, graph);
    printf("Details of graph, Nodes and Source: %d %d\n", graph->no_vertices, graph->source);
    printf("--Adjacency List--(Started from Vertex number 0)\n");
    graph -> list = adjacency_list(fnodes, graph);
    printf("Total Weight: %d\n", graph -> total_weight);
    print(graph);
    int distance_array_new[graph -> no_vertices]; //failed
    int *distance_array;
    distance_array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (graph -> no_vertices));
     if (distance_array == NULL) {
        printf("NO MEMORY\n");
     }
    /* NOTE: If I try to initialize the array normally, or read it's contents in a for loop,
    or try to change the value, check the pointer it gives a Seg fault and I don't know Why.
    Uncomment below code and Run */
    printf("V: %d\n", distance_array[0]);

     for (int i = 0; i < (graph -> no_vertices); i++)
     {
        distance_array[i] = (graph -> total_weight) + 15;
    }
     distance_array[(graph -> source) - 1] = 0; //Initial distance is 0 for source.
}
```

nodes.txt

```
5,1
1,4,25
1,2,45
2,4,20
3,2,18
4,3,19
4,5,11
3,5,17
```

Comment: Show us the code *which is failing*

Comment: ERROR - `[1]    85460 segmentation fault  ./dijkstra_new2`

Comment: Even better, please make a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: The *code*, not the error. We are not interested in seeing the working code, but the failing one.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add info.

Comment: The above code is the one that failed in the main function, I have added comments also. anything?

Comment: If we change "something" we don't know if you change the same "something" if something fails.

Comment: The code does not contain `array[(graph -> no_vertices)]` mentioned in your question

Comment: added the code.

Comment: Is every single line of that code really necessary to reproduce the crash?

Comment: I still don't see `array[(graph -> no_vertices)]`

Comment: No. But I could be doing something wrong in the previous code which luckily might run.

Comment: Changed the name

Comment: That's one of the reasons why you create the MCVE - to make sure that you know what code is failing and post it here.

Comment: `graph` is never allocated any memory as I can see.

Comment: Yes, but I could mess the code in my previous statements also?

Comment: @dsaharia You know you can test these things, right? Figuring out which parts are necessary to recreate the crash and which aren't is part of the debugging process. You're supposed to do that before posting here.

Comment: `graph = initialize_graph(fnodes, graph);` You put uninitialized pointer variable in and get same uninitialized variable back. No memory is allocated as Eugene mentioned

Comment: I see the problem now, Thank You
I will keep in mind the MCVE